# Turn a fixed-top-navbar into a static-top-navbar at breakpoint

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a fixed-top-navbar that works great.  When the screen gets small (say 720px or less), how can I transform the fixed-top-navbar into a static-top-navbar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your classes are wrong, they should be `navbar-fixed-top` and `navbar-static-top`. Second, here is Bootstrap's style for these classes:

```
.navbar-static-top {
  border-width: 0 0 1px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-static-top {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
}

.navbar-fixed-top,
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-width: 0 0 1px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-fixed-top,
  .navbar-fixed-bottom {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
}
```

What you can do is apply the styling from the class you want it to "become" (`navbar-static-top`) onto the class it is ( `navbar-fixed-top`) in cases where the screen is under your desired width. Personally I'd stick with the 768px they're already using, in which case, add this to your custom CSS, after the bootstrap CSS.

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
  position: relative;
  border-width: 0 0 1px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you :)  Points for you!